# How does PCloud API uploadtransfer endpoint work?

Tags: post, postman, pcloud

I've been trying to use PCloud API for a few days, until now everything was well documented but right now I am trying to transfer a file through their service: PCloud transfer  (https://transfer.pcloud.com/ if you are curious). It is done using the "/uploadtransfer" endpoint but I can't figure out how it works.

Currently, I've only tried this request through Postman, I found out you have to use `ppaccepted=yes` so you don't have the 2303 error, but now I am trying everything and I get an 1101 error (Invalid request). As I want to upload files, I use a POST request with multipart/form-data as I did previously with the "/uploadfile" endpoint and found [this](https://gist.github.com/prashanthca/d81555a800bbddc13c4f98cbd17aa76b) that makes me think it is the right way but I couldn't make the script work. So here is basically what I tried in plain HTML :

> POST /uploadtransfer?sendermail=dummy@mail.com&receivermails=dummy@mail.com&ppaccepted=yes HTTP/1.1
> Host: eapi.pcloud.com
> Content-Length: 246
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
> ------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="filename"
> Content-Type: 
> (data)
> ------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--

I tried deleting some parameters, I get a 1074 error (Please provide valid 'sendermail') if I skip the sendermail, but still the same error for skipping any other parameter (1101).